# What is the best way to find all the leaves or self if leaf in awesome_nested_set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, awesome-nested-set

I am using awesome_nested_set gem in rails
In my controller I want to return

if it is leaf object

```
[ Model.find(params[:id]) ]         # self object in array
```

and if it is not leaf, then

```
Model.find(params[:id]).leaves    # all the leaves of this object
```

What could be the best way to do so ?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking for but it appears that `a = Model.find(params[:id]); a.leaf? ? [a] : a.leaves` would produce the desired result.

Comment: that's exactly how I did it, but I was looking for a better way, if possible